# How can I enable debug mode in Middleman so I can see extra log output?

Tags: ruby, middleman

The docs seem not to mention anything, but I can see reference to `logger.debug "Some log message"` in the source code, which is currently not outputting anything in my dev environment.

How can I enable debug mode for the logger?

Answer (score 3):

Found it:

```
middleman server --verbose
```

Comment: also --instrument adds some additional logging